# Possible to measure EEG signals with an AM receiver antenna/circuit?

Tags: rf, sensor, electromagnetism, eeg

I'm having trouble understanding the importance of placing EEG electrodes directly on the skin. I used to think the reason for this was to pick up voltage differences between points on the skull, the assumption being brain activity induces voltages on the surrounding head structures including the skin. However, the difference in surface voltages may be due to muscle tension, blood flow, sweat, or other factors unrelated to brain activity. This leads me to wonder if placing "antenna" like electrodes around the head, but not necessarily in direct contact may capture the EEG signal equally effectively.

The only explanation I can find for the skin-touching electrode is the reduction of the 60Hz signal [1] from power lines. Does this mean, if we effectively filter out 60Hz, or go to a place without power lines (e.g. nature), a non-contact eeg electrode may work?

[1] https://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/physio/vlab/biomed_signals/eeg_n.htm

Comment: Not an 'AM antenna' but capacitive electrodes are showing some promise:- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5371775/

Answer (score 0):

The wavelength for EEG is 5 orders of magnitude greater than AM radio signals so the practical signal capture methods of a fixed capacitance being dependent on the gap to the live subcutaneous skin over the skull  might be less sensitive to motion variation but even less sensitive to signal pickup.

Considering ambient noise of power lines is also 5 orders of magnitude greater than EEG signals, that would make the idea a show stopper.

Although I have done very limited testing, my understanding indicates , the best signals will be captured by ;

- **maintaining a firm cap pressure** over the electrodes to minimize modulation of scalp pressure from motion artifact which creates a large modulated voltage from capacitance variation of a fixed charge ΔV=Q/ΔC
- maintain a high input impedance and high CMRR in the cables as well as INA
- maintain high quality shielded balanced twisted pairs using the Vcm as an active guard shield signal or use RLD signal as your Common mode active guard.